# System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord does not contain a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework-4, radgrid

**code behind**

```
    protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = DbContext.students.Select("it.name,it.subject");
    }

    protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        Hashtable values = new Hashtable();
        item.ExtractValues(values);
        student stdd = new student();
        item.UpdateValues(stdd);
        DbContext.AddTostudents(stdd);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        int roll = (int)item.GetDataKeyValue("rollno");
        //int t = Int32.Parse(roll);
        student stdd = DbContext.students.Where(p => p.rollno == roll).FirstOrDefault();
        item.UpdateValues(stdd);
        //DbContext.AddTostudents(stdd);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();

    }

    protected void RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        int roll=(int)item.GetDataKeyValue("rollno");
        student stdd = DbContext.students.Where(p => p.rollno == roll).FirstOrDefault();
        DbContext.DeleteObject(stdd);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();

    }
```

and getting error like DataBinding: 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord' does not contain a property with the name 'rollno'.i have my table name as student and columns as-rollno,name,subject.

Comment: *Where* are you getting the error?

Comment: when i run the project in browser it was displaying like--   DataBinding: 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord' does not contain a property with the name 'rollno'.

Comment: But presumably this is due to an exception - so indicate *where* in your code there's an exception. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you only select name and subject fields, try to add rollno field as well and try again

```
DbContext.students.Select("it.name,it.subject,it.rollno");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir,It is working well now thank you.

Comment: sir,here when update my record it is showing error--"The property 'subject' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified" in model1.designer at:public global::System.String subject
        {
            get
            {
                return _subject;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_subject != value)
                {
                 OnsubjectChanging(value);
                 ReportPropertyChanging("subject");
                  _subject = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);ReportPropertyChanged("subject");OnsubjectChanged();}}}